# How to extract into a new variable the last 11 characters of a string variable in SAS only if they are numbers

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with a variable with company names. Sometimes, these company names have a person ID as their last 11 characteres.

So I want to create a new variable with their last 11 characteres and keep it only if they are numbers.

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
DATA have;
  INPUT CompanyName;
  DATALINES;
ASASD FSFASD ASDFASDFASD
ASDFAS ADFASDF FDAFADFADF 01232143211
ADAFSAD ADSFASDF 03331286532
LKJLKJK KLKJKJL
LLKJLKJ FDAFASDF 75423243211
;
RUN;
```

I want a new variable with missing values for lines 1 and 4 and the last 11 numeric values for lines 2, 3 5 (`01232143211`, `03331286532`, `75423243211`).

What have I tried?

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WANT AS 
   SELECT 
       CompanyName,
       case when prxmatch('/^\d{11}$/', substr(CompanyName, length(CompanyName) - 10)) > 0 
               then substr(CompanyName, length(CompanyName) - 10) 
               else "" end as ID_OWNER,
      FROM have;
QUIT;
```

But I've got a new variable with all missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to do with SAS code instead of SQL code.

First makes sure your data step to create the example data actually works.

```
data have;
  input CompanyName $50. ;
datalines;
ASASD FSFASD ASDFASDFASD
ASDFAS ADFASDF FDAFADFADF 01232143211
ADAFSAD ADSFASDF 03331286532
LKJLKJK KLKJKJL
LLKJLKJ FDAFASDF 75423243211
;
```

Then if the string is long enough to have 11 characters then take the last 11 characters and make sure that they are all digits.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length id $11 ;
  if length(companyname) > 11 then do;
    id = substr(companyname,length(companyname)-10);
    if verify(id,'0123456789') then id=' ';
  end;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    CompanyName                                  id

 1     ASASD FSFASD ASDFASDFASD
 2     ASDFAS ADFASDF FDAFADFADF 01232143211    01232143211
 3     ADAFSAD ADSFASDF 03331286532             03331286532
 4     LKJLKJK KLKJKJL
 5     LLKJLKJ FDAFASDF 75423243211             75423243211
```

You might want to also remove the id value when it exists.  So add this ELSE statement after that last IF statement.

```
else companyname = substr(companyname,1,length(companyname)-11);
```

Results

```
Obs    CompanyName                      id

 1     ASASD FSFASD ASDFASDFASD
 2     ASDFAS ADFASDF FDAFADFADF    01232143211
 3     ADAFSAD ADSFASDF             03331286532
 4     LKJLKJK KLKJKJL
 5     LLKJLKJ FDAFASDF             75423243211
```